# how to only show failed CASE statements in a SQL query

Tags: sql, case

I need to only show failed records in the below query how can i do it,

```
SELECT
    E.MEMNO, 
    '' ,
    E.EXITDATE, 
    S.STASTART, 
    E.STATUS, 
    S.SSTA, 
    E.STATUSDATE,
    S.RN,
    CASE 
        WHEN E.EXITDATE >= S.STASTART 
            THEN 'Pass' 
            ELSE 'Fail'  
    END 
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM EXITRETIREMENT 
     WHERE STATUS IN (35, 45, 55, 75))  AS E 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MEMNO ORDER BY STASTART DESC) Rn  
     FROM STATHIS) S ON E.MEMNO = S.MEMNO
WHERE       
    rn = 2
```

Comment: `..where rn=2 and CASE WHEN E.EXITDATE >= S.STASTART then 'Pass' else 'Fail'  END = 'Fail'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select E.MEMNO, 
            '' ,
            E.EXITDATE, 
            S.STASTART, 
            E.STATUS, 
            S.SSTA, 
            E.STATUSDATE,
            S.RN,
            CASE 
                WHEN E.EXITDATE >= S.STASTART 
                then 'Pass' else 'Fail' 
            END 
    FROM   (Select * from EXITRETIREMENT where STATUS in  (35, 45, 55, 75))  AS E 
    INNER JOIN
            (SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER()Over(PARTITION by MEMNO Order by STASTART desc) Rn  
             FROM STATHIS ) S 
    ON E.MEMNO = S.MEMNO and E.EXITDATE < S.STASTART
    WHERE      
          rn = 2
```